# How to remove ROLE_ prefix from Spring Security?

Tags: spring-security

I have read many discussions, even on this forum, and I have found many suggestions but I have not found valid code.

I use Spring Boot **2.5.1** and **Java 11** but I want to keep my application up to date. I need a code that is possibly valid also in the future.

**Is there official Spring support?**

Comment: Do read through official Spring Security Documentation : [Common Built-In Expressions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#el-common-built-in) and [DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.setDefaultRolePrefix()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/access/expression/DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.html#setDefaultRolePrefix(java.lang.String))

Comment: It does not explain how to do it.

Comment: There are many solutions on the internet but few work. Also, in my opinion, it is risky to remove "ROLE_" because as soon as a new version of Spring Boot comes out my application may stop working. I have found a code that works after many failed attempts. Updating your code every time you update your version of Spring Security is a bloodbath.
Saying to read the documentation is tantamount to not answering.

Comment: You have not shared what you have read , what you have tried out or what you think is invalid code , it is all left to reader's imagination . I was just trying to help and meant no offense . Official support can be found in the official documentation and with all due respect , that is why it is a "comment" and not an "answer". If you wish to share with others what you have found out , you have the option to answer this question as well.